# Print 2 columns in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
df_heartdis = pd.read_csv('processed.cleveland.data.csv', na_values='?')
df_heartdis.columns['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach', 'exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope',\
    'ca', 'thal', 'num']

print('class labels = {}'.format(df_heartdis(['num'],['chol'])))
```

In my dataframe I have 14 columns, out of that, I want to print 2 columns side by side. I tried using

```
print('class labels = {}'.format(df_heartdis(['num'],['chol'])))
```

but it is throwing error, though one column can be printed by using

```
print('class labels = {}'.format(df_heartdis(['num'])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the column headers in the creation of the dataframe.
Selecting specific columns is done using the `.loc` function.

Below code should work:

```
df_heartdis = pd.read_csv('processed.cleveland.data.csv', na_values='?', names = ['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 'thalach','exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope','ca', 'thal', 'num'])

print('class labels = {}'.format(df_heartdis.loc[:, ['num', 'chol']]))
```

Here, the `.loc` function selects all rows (`:`) of the `num` and `chol` columns.

Comment: Hi Schmoerff, thank you very much is working, the only concern I have that due to long message "class labels={}" I am not getting the values of the columns just below the name of column. Can I do something for that also ?

Comment: You could remove `'class labels = {}'.format(`. This will just print the table, and make it line up like it should.
Alternatively, replace `class labels = {}` with `'class labels = \n{}'` to add a newline.
Please accept my answer so others may be helped by it if you are satisfied with the result.